# Login Test - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel and was attempting to test a user login but since I've started using in memory sqlite I've been having problems. My Code:

```
$user = factory(App\User::class)->create
    ([
        'email'=>'testuser@email.com',
        'password'=>'passwordtest'
    ]);

    $this->visit('/auth/login')
        ->type('testuser@email.com', 'email')
        ->type('passwordtest', 'password')
        ->press('Login')
        ->seePageIs('/home');
```

When I run this code it never makes it past the login page. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encrypt the password:

```
$user = factory(App\User::class)->create
([
    'email'=>'testuser@email.com',
    'password'=>bcrypt('passwordtest')
]);
```